# Waiting for service operation in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions AND didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called after delay

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, appdelegate

I am not sure where exactly my question fit. Here is the issue :
I want the push notifications to be registered on application start. For which I am registering in **AppDelegate** `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[manager registerForPushNotifications];
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

If I don't use `GCD`, `return YES;` of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called first and in that case, my my service method, which want to call from `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` for sending device token is not called.

```
// system push notification registration success callback, delegate to pushManager
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:token forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [self registerForPushWooshNotification];
    [[PushNotificationManager pushManager] handlePushRegistration:deviceToken];
}  

-(void)registerForPushWooshNotification
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"TokenId": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"deviceToken"]
                             };

    [_sharedHandler.requestManager POST:TGURL_PUSHWOOSH_NOTIFICATION
                             parameters:params
                                success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                    NSError *e;
                                    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
                                    NSLog(@"------ Registered for Pushwoosh ------");
                                }
                                failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                }];
}
```

But as I have implemented the `GCD`, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` never gets called.

**Summary** :

**1. I have to register application on app start.

2. Web Service needs to be called on app start.

3. If GCD not used : return YES; is called first, and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken gets called after delay.

4. If GCD used : didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is never called.**

I had searched for [**didFinishLaunchingWithOptions wait**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=m9-4VLLzOIrC8geSzoGgBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=didfinishlaunchingwithoptions+wait) and [**didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called after delay**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=m9-4VLLzOIrC8geSzoGgBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken+called+after+delay) on google before posting this question but no success.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that by waiting on the semaphore, you are blocking the main thread, and the callback you are expecting to happen later will be delivered on the main thread. Since you're blocking the main thread, the callback will never happen. If you want your app to not do anything until that callback is received, you have to set that up another way.

The solution that would be philosophically closest to what you have now would be to spin the main run loop while waiting waiting for the callback, but there are a number of different ways to do it, and that's probably not the way I would choose. That said, if you wanted to do it that way, it might look something like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{
    BOOL didRegisterCalled;
    NSData* token;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    NSLog(@"registerForRemoteNotifications called. waiting for callback.");

    while (!didRegisterCalled)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate: [NSDate date]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Register call back happened, and execution resumed");

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    didRegisterCalled = YES;
    token = [deviceToken copy];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    didRegisterCalled = YES;
    token = nil;
}

@end
```

The simplest way would be to split your startup tasks into a separate method and have the callback call that method. (FWIW, this is probably the approach I would choose.) That might look like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{
    BOOL didRegisterCalled;
    NSData* token;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"Calling registerForRemoteNotifications and deferring the rest of app startup.");
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    return YES;
}

- (void)theRestOfTheAppStartupProcess
{
    NSLog(@"Finishing app startup now that registration has happened.");
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    token = [deviceToken copy];
    if (!didRegisterCalled)
    {
        didRegisterCalled = YES;
        [self theRestOfTheAppStartupProcess];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    token = nil;
    if (!didRegisterCalled)
    {
        didRegisterCalled = YES;
        [self theRestOfTheAppStartupProcess];
    }
}

@end
```

Another way might be to set up a dispatch queue, suspend it, and then have the callback resume it. That might look like this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
{
    dispatch_queue_t appStartupQueue;
    NSData* token;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    appStartupQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_suspend(appStartupQueue);
    dispatch_set_target_queue(appStartupQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue());
    dispatch_async(appStartupQueue, ^{
        [self theRestOfTheAppStartupProcess];
    });

    NSLog(@"Calling registerForRemoteNotifications and deferring the rest of app startup.");
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    return YES;
}

- (void)theRestOfTheAppStartupProcess
{
    NSLog(@"Finishing app startup now that registration has happened.");
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    token = [deviceToken copy];
    if (appStartupQueue)
    {
        dispatch_resume(appStartupQueue);
        appStartupQueue = nil;
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    token = nil;
    if (appStartupQueue)
    {
        dispatch_resume(appStartupQueue);
        appStartupQueue = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

But what you have currently is going to produce a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I as where shall be the web service call and shall the application wait for it to complete i.e. will I get response back? Because in my implementation(without GCD), success or failure block of service call never gets called as I am returned from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: Being returned from `-application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` has nothing to do with whether or not your success or failure method gets called. It sounds like you might want to read up on "run loops" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html